# Setting QWidget background color artifacts

Tags: qt, background-color, qwidget

I have a parent QWidget which contains some child widgets managed with layout. When I set parent's backgound color it doesn't cover some area near a child - for example rounded QScrollBar and a frame around QSpinBox. Is there a way to make parent's backgound to cover a child's content-free area fully?
[image: QSpinBox]
[image: QScrollBar]

Comment: Try making the child background transparent ?

Comment: @Thalia, unfortunately, that didn't help

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qspinbox (the slider just above it) - may help, perhaps it is the border... How are you making them round ? I would experiment but don't see the option.

Comment: @Thalia, oh yes, setting up the border solves my problem. I didn't set it at all - it was just a system appearance (Ubuntu)

Comment: I'll post that as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the objects border.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qspinbox
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qslider

has examples on changing appearances using style sheets.